# How can i delete an object from a Polymorphic relation many to many in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I have this db schema

travel: is, name

service: id, name

picture: id, name

picturable: picture_id, picturable_id, picturable_type.

travel and service can have pictures so i declare a  Polymorphic relation in this models

Travel.php

```
public function pictures()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('Picture', 'picturable');
}
```

Service.php

```
  public function pictures()
  {
      return $this->morphToMany('Picture', 'picturable');
  }
```

Picture.php

```
public function travels()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('Travel', 'picturable');
}

public function services()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('Service', 'picturable');
}
```

i create the relarion with

```
$this->service->pictures()->save(Picture::find(Input::get( 'new_picture' )) );
```

but when i try to delete, i doesn't work

```
$service->pictures()->detach();
```

Comment: I think detach() will just remove the association, delete() will delete the records physically.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, everything was ok, just a bug in validation. problem solved.